# Meta query ignores multiple values of the key

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-query

I have the following post meta for posts:

```
_post_allowed_countries

//Example value: 
array ( 0 => 'en', 1 => 'gr', )

// A list of allowed countries
```

and

```
_post_allowed_countries_not

//Example value: 
array ( 0 => '0' )

// True/False -> If true ( '1' ), _post_allowed_countries act as disallowed countries
```

and this is my meta query:

```
array(
    'relation'              => 'OR',
    array(
        'relation'          => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation'      => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       =>'_post_allowed_countries_not',
                'value'     => '',
                'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       =>'_post_allowed_countries_not',
                'value'     => '0',
                'compare'   => '='
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'key'       =>'_post_allowed_countries',
            'value'     => serialize('gr'),
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       =>'_post_allowed_countries_not',
            'value'     => '1',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       =>'_post_allowed_countries',
            'value'     => serialize('gr'),
            'compare'   => 'NOT LIKE'
        )
    ),
)
```

So basically I am trying to query all the posts that have `gr` as one of their allowed counties or they don't have `gr` as one of their disallowed countries ( `gr` in reality is the current's visitor country code ).

The problem seems to be that the meta query only checks for the first value of `_post_allowed_countries`. Is there any way to fix this?

**Note:** Yes I know it's easier to do this with taxonomies but at this point it's not an option for me. I need to make this work with post meta.

**Note 2:** It's not that I can't convert this to taxonomies. It's that I want to avoid taxonomies for a couple of reasons which are irrelevant to the question.

**Note 3:** No, I don't store serialized data for `_post_allowed_countries`. The array I posted is just an example of what is stored. I actually add multiple post meta for the same key.

**EDIT:** After a lot of testing with `'compare' = '='` and `'compare' = '!='` I think only the `!=` doesn't work as expected because it validates at the first match. In that case is it possible to tell the `!=` meta query part to check for all meta values of `_post_allowed_countries` key?

Comment: You shouldn't store serialized data if you want to query for it, and there's no need if you're storing a plain list. You can have multiple post meta with the same key on a post and retrieve them all as an array using the 3rd parameter of `get_post_meta`. Also there's no reason you can't convert to taxonomies, even a post meta save hook to add and remove terms would work, a WP CLI or cron job to convert existing data

Comment: @TomJNowell I don't store them as serialized data, I actually add multiple post data on the same key ( `_post_allowed_countries` ), the example I posted is just to show what is stored. I never said I can't convert to taxonomies.

Comment: @TomJNowell I already tried with `'value' => 'gr', 'compare' => '='` or `'value' => ['gr'], 'compare' => 'IN'` but they failed as well.

Comment: if that's the case then why do you call `serialize`? It'll produce the string `s:2:"gr";` which isn't what's stored in post meta

Comment: @TomJNowell Because that was the last thing I tried. I thought that maybe meta query serializes multiple values from the same key. Anyways please check my EDIT, I think I am closer to the actual problem now.